# Firebase Hosting proxy to Cloud Functions only triggers in us-central1

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have my firebase cloud functions created with region: asia-northeast1, I am trying to trigger one of the functions using the firebase.json file.

```
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "ksite",
      "public": "public",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        { "source": "**", "function": "ssr" }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Unfortunately this triggers the function with region of `us-central1` https://us-central1-site.cloudfunctions.net/ssr/  instead of `asia-northeast1` something like this https://asia-northeast1-site.cloudfunctions.net/ssr/

How and why is this happening?

Here is my function:

```
// For Universal Rendering
export const ssr = functions.region('asia-northeast1').https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    require(`${process.cwd()}/dist/ksite-webpack/server`).app(request, response);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Hosting currently only supports the proxy of URLs to functions deployed to us-central1, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions):

> Important: Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only.

And also [here in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations):

> Important: If you are using HTTP functions to serve dynamic content for Firebase Hosting, you must use us-central1.

Comment: This is just so insane... it's June 2020 and the situation is still the same. Absolutely bonkers. It automatically renders many many sites useless for companies outside the US. Server side rendering via functions is not viable outside the US.. insanity

Comment: @Spock Feel free to file a feature request with Firebase support. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @Dough I'm sure they're aware... they even mention in the documentation that functions are for US only (if it's a http function)..  so nobody in Europe can use functions.. which means no server side rendering, no api, no micro service.. we'll have to deploy full node servers to App Engine instead..

Comment: @Spock You could use Cloud Run instead.

Comment: @Dough thanks yeah I've thought of it, right now I deploy a node server to App Engine and it suits me well.. but Cloud Run seems promising.. thanks

Comment: @DougStevenson do you think these things need to be filed ? shouldnt these things we done by company in the first place

Comment: How about calling a regional function such as function("asia-northeast1") within an app hosted via  cloud functions on Firebase Hosting? It seems to be working fine, but there is potential risk doing this perhaps??